# How can I re-download the old drivers for the WiFi card on my PC?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, wifi-driver

I have a Dell XPS 8500 which is running Windows 10 Pro and I tried changing the WiFi card but after that, the Bluetooth and WiFi stopped working

A few days ago I tried to download drivers from Dell’s website but it said that the drivers are dated back to October 2013.

The WiFi card is a Dell Wireless 1703 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHz) and none of the drivers are working even if I find the most recent ones.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Windows update should install the latest drivers.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried changing the WiFi card but after that, the Bluetooth & WiFi
> stopped working and a few days ago I tried to download drivers from
> dell.com but it said that the drivers are dated back to October 2013.
> The WiFi card is a Dell Wireless 1703 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHz) and none of
> the drivers are working even if I find the most recent ones.

It is doubtful old drivers will fix things.  Ask to return the Wireless Card for a replacement card.

Also consider getting a USB wireless card for comparison.

I would first try replacing the existing card with an exact Dell replacement.

**Followup:**  The computer is old enough and far enough out of date that it should be replaced.

Comment: Or just get an inexpensive USB WiFi adapter, many of which cost less than US$10. Being external, it's easy to orient for best reception (by its antenna or on extension/hub). Think outside the box.

Comment: Hey John I cant return the wifi card because the old one broke and i had another Dell Xps 8500 and i took it from there. I also tried the usb wireless card but it still doesnt work because my wifi router is in another room and i cannot take it out of the room.

Comment: If no wireless cards work in your machine (3 - 1 broke, 1 from another machine, 1 USB wireless), you may need to get the machine serviced.

Comment: the usb card works but the connection is slow and the computer is out of its service daate

Comment: he computer is out of its service date .......   Think about my suggestion to have the machine serviced locally . It may be time for a replacement computer.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest you or anyone experiencing similar issues, to isolate if the wifi issue is a hardware at fault or related to a driver by using a Linux Live USB stick and you just need an empty pen drive (thumb drive) of size 4GB or more and booting from Linux Live stick.

Please note, Linux includes drivers for all Major manufacturers and devices works out of the box without any configurations (provided no hardware issues are there).

You may use this easy to use article in case you are new to Linux (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview).

Answer (score 0):

For an older card (or any hardware), it's not surprising for drivers to stop receiving updates. The most recent one ([here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails/?driverid=9t8xy)) I found is July 2015

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).